# How to fix python serial monitor parsing error?

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial, arduino-uno, serial-monitor

When i tryied to light the LED from python with this code:

```
import serial
arduino_port = 'COM5'  
arduino_baudrate = 9600
arduino = serial.Serial(arduino_port, arduino_baudrate)
def send_command_to_arduino(command):
arduino.write(command.encode())
send_command_to_arduino('2,1')
```

i have this error in arduino Output:
`> avrdude: stk500_recv():

> programmer is not responding avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10:
> not in sync: resp=0x93 arduino.
> (
> in arduino i have this code to parse serial monitor:

```
#include "Parser.h"

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); 
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(12, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(11, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 1) {
    char str[30];
    int amount = Serial.readBytesUntil(';', str, 30);
    str[amount] = NULL;
      Parser data(str, ',');
      int ints[5];
      int am = data.parseInts(ints);
      switch (ints[0]) { 
      case 0: digitalWrite(10, ints[1]); break;
      case 1: digitalWrite(12, ints[1]); break;
      case 2: digitalWrite(11, ints[1]); break;
      case 3:
        analogWrite(3, ints[1]);
        analogWrite(5, ints[2]);
        analogWrite(6, ints[3]);
        break;
      }
  }
}
```

i have arduino UNO

It firs time i get this error, so i don`t know what i should try.

Comment: What parsing error? All I can see is UPLOAD error and invalid indentation in python def send_command_to_arduino(command):

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to arduino and I must have made a mistake. In fact, there is an indentation, but here I must have accidentally removed it. I'm trying to send a key to the "Serial Monitor" to turn on the LED but when the program starts I get a send error. If you have had experience solving similar problems, I would be very grateful for your help

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how, but everything was fixed after a reboot :)

Comment: I cannot see how rebooting would fix your problem, if the function in your python code is not indented, then there is no way that you are actually sending anything with the arduino. The only thing that a reboot can do is change the actual address of your connection to the correct COM5 (but without seeing this myself I cannot draw a definite conclusion)